# object does not respond to selector

Tags: objective-c, ios

This may be very basic, but I've done a lot of Googling and can't seem to figure out what's wrong.  I'm trying to move an image from an iOS app's sandboxed data folder to the "Camera Roll".

If I use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,nil,nil,nil)`, it throws no error but also does not save a copy of the image in Photos.

In order to figure out why it's failing, I attempted to implemented a selector (below), but now it throws an NSInvalidArgumentException with reason "MyTest<...> does not respond to selector image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"

Here is my implementation:

```
@implementation MyTest

- (void)
    image:(UIImage *) image
    didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
    contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
{
    //log error or do stuff...
}

+ (void) moveToCameraRoll: (NSString *) path
{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:path] retain];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);
}

@end
```

I feel like this is probably extremely basic, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `+moveToCameraRoll:` is a class (i.e., static) method, the `self` reference in the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function is pointing to the `MyTest` class. The selector you are trying to use is an instance method and thus only instances of `MyTest`, but not the `MyTest` class itself, will respond to that selector.

To fix this, change your `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` method to a class method.

Answer (score 2):

If you provide that selector (which is optional) then you must implement a method with that name:

```
+ (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
}
```

This is complicated by the fact that you are trying to do this in a class method instead of an instance method.

Unless you really need to handle this case, you can pass `nil` instead of the selector.

Comment: The problem is you implemented it as an instance method but `self` is the class, not an instance. Try making the `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` method a class method like I showed.